# How do I make this iframe fit to the page both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I have the following sandbox from Material UI: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-c8e39?file=/demo.js

When the page loads, it will load some HTML in an iframe. While the width seems to fit fine, the vertical size doesn't and shows 2 scrollbars. How do I get rid of the outer scrollbar? The idea is to load any size html and be able to dynamically fit it to the height of the html. If that html is longer, then it should show just 1 scrollbar, not the two it currently has.

Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [html, setHtml] = React.useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setHtml(`<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title></title>
          <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
          #table_wrapper{
            overflow-x: hidden;
          }
          .mdc-data-table{
            width: 100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table id="jEZeucEZQISp" class="display" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>STATE</th>
              <th>CAPITAL</th>
              <th>WIKIPEDIA LINK</th>
              <th>VISITED</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var my_jquery = $.noConflict(true);
          my_jquery(document).ready(function(){
            my_jquery('#jEZeucEZQISp').DataTable({
              data: [["Alabama","Montgomery","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery,_Alabama","TRUE"],["Alaska","Juneau","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneau,_Alaska","TRUE"],["Arizona","Phoenix","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix,_Arizona","TRUE"],["Arkansas","Little Rock","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Rock,_Arkansas","TRUE"],["California","Sacramento","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramento,_California","TRUE"],["Colorado","Denver","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver,_Colorado","TRUE"],["Connecticut","Hartford","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartford,_Connecticut","TRUE"],["Delaware","Dover","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dover,_Delaware","FALSE"],["Florida","Tallahassee","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallahassee,_Florida","TRUE"],["Georgia","Atlanta","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta,_Georgia","TRUE"],["Hawaii","Honolulu","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honolulu,_Hawaii","TRUE"],["Idaho","Boise","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boise,_Idaho","TRUE"],["Illinois","Springfield","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield,_Illinois","TRUE"],["Indiana","Indianapolis","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis,_Indiana","TRUE"],["Iowa","Des Moines","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des%20Moines,_Iowa","TRUE"],["Kansas","Topeka","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topeka,_Kansas","TRUE"],["Kentucky","Frankfort","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfort,_Kentucky","TRUE"],["Louisiana","Baton Rouge","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baton%20Rouge,_Louisiana","TRUE"],["Maine","Augusta","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusta,_Maine","TRUE"],["Maryland","Annapolis","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapolis,_Maryland","TRUE"],["Massachusetts","Boston","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston,_Massachusetts","TRUE"],["Michigan","Lansing","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lansing,_Michigan","TRUE"],["Minnesota","St. Paul","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St.%20Paul,_Minnesota","TRUE"],["Mississippi","Jackson","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson,_Mississippi","TRUE"],["Missouri","Jefferson City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson%20City,_Missouri","TRUE"],["Montana","Helena","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helena,_Montana","TRUE"],["Nebraska","Lincoln","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln,_Nebraska","TRUE"],["Nevada","Carson City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carson%20City,_Nevada","TRUE"],["New Hampshire","Concord","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord,_New%20Hampshire","TRUE"],["New Jersey","Trenton","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trenton,_New%20Jersey","TRUE"],["New Mexico","Santa Fe","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa%20Fe,_New%20Mexico","TRUE"],["New York","Albany","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albany,_New%20York","TRUE"],["North Carolina","Raleigh","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raleigh,_North%20Carolina","TRUE"],["North Dakota","Bismarck","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismarck,_North%20Dakota","TRUE"],["Ohio","Columbus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus,_Ohio","TRUE"],["Oklahoma","Oklahoma City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma%20City,_Oklahoma","TRUE"],["Oregon","Salem","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem,_Oregon","TRUE"],["Pennsylvania","Harrisburg","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrisburg,_Pennsylvania","TRUE"],["Rhode Island","Providence","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Providence,_Rhode%20Island","TRUE"],["South Carolina","Columbia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia,_South%20Carolina","TRUE"],["South Dakota","Pierre","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre,_South%20Dakota","TRUE"],["Tennessee","Nashville","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashville,_Tennessee","TRUE"],["Texas","Austin","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin,_Texas","TRUE"],["Utah","Salt Lake City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt%20Lake%20City,_Utah","TRUE"],["Vermont","Montpelier","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montpelier,_Vermont","TRUE"],["Virginia","Richmond","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richmond,_Virginia","TRUE"],["Washington","Olympia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia,_Washington","TRUE"],["West Virginia","Charleston","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charleston,_West%20Virginia","TRUE"],["Wisconsin","Madison","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madison,_Wisconsin","TRUE"],["Wyoming","Cheyenne","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne,_Wyoming","TRUE"]],
              iDisplayLength:  25 ,
              "scrollX":      false,
              scrollY:        '',
              scrollCollapse:  false ,
              search: {
                search: "",
              },
            });
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>`);
  }, []);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Paper
          elevation={1}
          style={{ minHeight: "auto", height: "100vh" }}
          flex={1}
          overflow="auto"
        >
          <iframe
            id="widget"
            name="widget"
            title="widget"
            scrolling="yes"
            frameBorder="0"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            srcdoc={html}
            style={{ position: "relative", height: "100%" }}
          ></iframe>
        </Paper>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want the content to be scrollable with one scroll bar (which will be the main body scroll bar) or no scroll at all that means the iframe will resize to fit  (100% x 100% size )

Comment: Just an idea. If you are the developer of the `code` that comes with the iFrame, maybe you can use PostMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage to post a message from your iframe's code to tell your main content how much height the iFrame needs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly adjust the div outside the iframe to fit the content vertically. try reducing vh of the outer div. once the outer div is properly adjusted to fit vertically he outer scroll will disappear.

but if you want to forcefully hide the outer scrollbar then checkout this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_hide_scrollbar_keep_func)

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML that you are generating modify the `<script>` tag to add the following `resizeIframe` function and a call to that function at the end on the document ready event:

```
        <script>
          function resizeIframe()
          {
            var document = window.parent.document;
            var iframe = document.getElementById('widget');
            iframe.style.height = (iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 18) + 'px';
          }

          var my_jquery = $.noConflict(true);
          my_jquery(document).ready(function(){
            my_jquery('#jEZeucEZQISp').DataTable({
              data: [["Alabama","Montgomery","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery,_Alabama","TRUE"],["Alaska","Juneau","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneau,_Alaska","TRUE"],["Arizona","Phoenix","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix,_Arizona","TRUE"],["Arkansas","Little Rock","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Rock,_Arkansas","TRUE"],["California","Sacramento","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramento,_California","TRUE"],["Colorado","Denver","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver,_Colorado","TRUE"],["Connecticut","Hartford","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartford,_Connecticut","TRUE"],["Delaware","Dover","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dover,_Delaware","FALSE"],["Florida","Tallahassee","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallahassee,_Florida","TRUE"],["Georgia","Atlanta","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta,_Georgia","TRUE"],["Hawaii","Honolulu","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honolulu,_Hawaii","TRUE"],["Idaho","Boise","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boise,_Idaho","TRUE"],["Illinois","Springfield","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield,_Illinois","TRUE"],["Indiana","Indianapolis","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis,_Indiana","TRUE"],["Iowa","Des Moines","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des%20Moines,_Iowa","TRUE"],["Kansas","Topeka","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topeka,_Kansas","TRUE"],["Kentucky","Frankfort","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfort,_Kentucky","TRUE"],["Louisiana","Baton Rouge","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baton%20Rouge,_Louisiana","TRUE"],["Maine","Augusta","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusta,_Maine","TRUE"],["Maryland","Annapolis","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapolis,_Maryland","TRUE"],["Massachusetts","Boston","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston,_Massachusetts","TRUE"],["Michigan","Lansing","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lansing,_Michigan","TRUE"],["Minnesota","St. Paul","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St.%20Paul,_Minnesota","TRUE"],["Mississippi","Jackson","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson,_Mississippi","TRUE"],["Missouri","Jefferson City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson%20City,_Missouri","TRUE"],["Montana","Helena","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helena,_Montana","TRUE"],["Nebraska","Lincoln","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln,_Nebraska","TRUE"],["Nevada","Carson City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carson%20City,_Nevada","TRUE"],["New Hampshire","Concord","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord,_New%20Hampshire","TRUE"],["New Jersey","Trenton","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trenton,_New%20Jersey","TRUE"],["New Mexico","Santa Fe","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa%20Fe,_New%20Mexico","TRUE"],["New York","Albany","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albany,_New%20York","TRUE"],["North Carolina","Raleigh","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raleigh,_North%20Carolina","TRUE"],["North Dakota","Bismarck","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismarck,_North%20Dakota","TRUE"],["Ohio","Columbus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus,_Ohio","TRUE"],["Oklahoma","Oklahoma City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma%20City,_Oklahoma","TRUE"],["Oregon","Salem","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem,_Oregon","TRUE"],["Pennsylvania","Harrisburg","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrisburg,_Pennsylvania","TRUE"],["Rhode Island","Providence","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Providence,_Rhode%20Island","TRUE"],["South Carolina","Columbia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia,_South%20Carolina","TRUE"],["South Dakota","Pierre","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre,_South%20Dakota","TRUE"],["Tennessee","Nashville","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashville,_Tennessee","TRUE"],["Texas","Austin","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin,_Texas","TRUE"],["Utah","Salt Lake City","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt%20Lake%20City,_Utah","TRUE"],["Vermont","Montpelier","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montpelier,_Vermont","TRUE"],["Virginia","Richmond","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richmond,_Virginia","TRUE"],["Washington","Olympia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia,_Washington","TRUE"],["West Virginia","Charleston","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charleston,_West%20Virginia","TRUE"],["Wisconsin","Madison","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madison,_Wisconsin","TRUE"],["Wyoming","Cheyenne","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne,_Wyoming","TRUE"]],
              iDisplayLength:  25 ,
              "scrollX":      true,
              scrollY:        '',
              scrollCollapse:  false ,
              search: {
                search: "",
              },
            });
            resizeIframe();
            my_jquery(window.parent).on('resize', resizeIframe);
          });
        </script>
```

Then change your `<IFRAME>` tag to:

```
          <iframe
            id="widget"
            name="widget"
            title="widget"
            scrolling="auto"
            frameBorder="0"
            width="100%"
            srcDoc={html}
            style={{ position: "relative"}}
          ></iframe>
```

[View on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iwpdn?file=/demo.js:11013-11280)

Comment: I'm curious, why do you add 18px for?

Comment: I am glad you asked! It's just that when **running in the sandbox but not in a full window**, you do get that unwanted horizontal scrollbar and for that you need the 18 extra pixels to account for the height of the scrollbar. **But if there is any chance of the horizontal scrollbar appearing because the browser window is made sufficiently small, then you should include the 18 extra pixels**.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add an event handler for the `resize` event of the parent window. This also takes care of it looking correct in the small sandbox window and fixes a problem I just discovered where you got an extra vertical scrollbar if the windows gets to narrow. I have also set property `scrollX` to `true`. Otherwise, you will not get horizontal scrollbars at all (at least not on Internet Explorer) if the window is made sufficiently small and the overflow will be hidden.

Comment: Please don't solve css issues with Javascript it's an absolute overkill.

Comment: @johannchopin It's a question of aesthetics. You end up with a vertical scrollbar on the iframe while I end up with one on the browser window. As long as the iframe's width is 100% then your solution looks fairly close to mine. Granted in this particular case  it may seem like overkill. But mine is a general solution especially when you do not have control over the content that is being displayed in the iframe. Suppose the page you needed to display consisted of a 400px-wide left-justified table that you wanted centered in the parent page? Your scrollbar would look quite different than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix that by giving the full screen height to the `div#root` by using `style={{ height: "100vh" }}` and adapt the height from the `iframe`'s parent to:

```
  <Paper elevation={1} style={{ height: "90%" }} flex={1} overflow="auto">
    <iframe
      id="widget"
      name="widget"
      title="widget"
      ...
```

Here is a link to the codesandbox:

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` cannot resize itself (otherwise advertisers would be able to increase the size of their ads in web pages without their consent)

That means the parent is always responsible of setting a height to an `iframe`. It could read directly the `iframe` content's height and set the `iframe` height accordingly like this:

```
const iframeRef = React.createRef();
const [iframeHeight, setIframeHeight] = React.useState('100%');

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIframeHeight(`${iframeRef.current.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight}px`);
}, []);

const iframeRef = React.createRef();

<iframe
  ref={iframeRef}
  id="widget"
  name="widget"
  title="widget"
  scrolling="yes"
  frameBorder="0"
  width="100%"
  height={iframeHeight}
  srcdoc={html}
  style={{ position: "relative", height: iframeHeight }}
></iframe>
```

And if the `iframe` height is prone to change (on some asynchronous operation, or user interaction), then you have to emit messages from the `iframe` to its parent with [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) when the height has changed. The message would contain the new height.
Then add an event listener on the [`message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) event in the parent and set the new height to the `iframe`.